# Android SQlite database table, adding column

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to add a column to my database table which was created a while back and every time i try to run the app with the new column in the database adapter it crashes.

Why is this happening? I have changed the name of the database so it acts like a fresh table but this still doesn't work..

Please help????

Comment: What errors do you get? Show us logcat output.

Comment: With regrets, the stackoverflow crystal ball, which would permit deep introspection into your problem, is experiencing technical difficulties and is unavailable to service your request. Please deposit relevant information to permit our backup hamsters to understand the nature of your difficulty. [Translated -- got a crash dump?]

Comment: I assume the database adapter is updated accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` as a lot of the Android examples suggest, you need to increment the DB_VERSION int that gets passed to the constructor.  Otherwise the `onUpgrade` method doesn't get called and your db schema doesn't change.